# Using transitive verbs in passive voice

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice

Consider a sentence:

> A document was shared with me.

Can I turn it into a sentence with <del>Passive voice</del> (*me* being a subject)? This doesn't sound right:

> I was shared with a document.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Um, passive voice is [formed](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/passive) like this: subject + finite form of to be + past participle. Where is "finite form of to be" in your sentence? Or what am I missing?

Comment: Of course it is not possible.The clause you want to express in the passive voice is _already_ in the passive voice!

Comment: Well, I've missed that. But my point was to come up with a sentence that goes like this: I was shared ... a document. Like in, I was told...

Comment: Or maybe, "I was shared a document" will do?

Comment: I guess you are talking about ditransitive verbs. You may want to check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb

Comment: you were supplied with a document by...

Comment: "To share" doesn't seem like ditransitive verb. I can't possibly say, "I shared him a document." And let me make it clear, I'm talking about Google Documents. Which you can share with other people. Having that said, is anything wrong with "I was shared a document"?

Comment: _"I was shared a document"_ is an impossibility in English. When you begin with _"I was shared..."_ you make the pronoun _I_ the _patient_ of the verb in the passive voice. In such a clause, it is _I_ that undergoes the action of being shared. Once you have begun the sentence with this passive voice clause, the NP _a document_ is orphaned. It has nowehere to go. It belongs to no element in the sentence. The _intransitive_ form of the verb _share_ (as in _"I shared a document with you"_) can't be used in a passive voice clause; in English, only transitive verbs have the passive voice.

Comment: Aren't you mistaken by any chance? The verb _share_ is in its transitive form in "I shared a document". It's just that not all transitive verbs can be put into passive voice with indirect object as a subject. According to @BobRodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As P. E. Dant says, your first sentence *is* in the passive voice. If it were in the active voice, it would look like this:

> Someone shared a document with me.

The point about the passive voice is to emphasize the object more than the subject. This is especially typical when the subject is undefined, and the active voice would have a subject like *someone* or *somebody*. Consider this sentence:

> A dinner was given in grandmother's honor.

Here, we don't care to explain who gave the dinner. Rather, the object—the dinner—is the important thing. Now, suppose we did care who gave the dinner. We might say this:

> The company gave a dinner in grandmother's honor.

Now, we're in active voice. The company is the subject, and a dinner is the object. We could also say this:

> A dinner was given by the company in grandmother's honor.

Whether we use the active or the passive voice in this situation is a matter of style. Most style guides advise not to use the passive voice in this situation.

Now, let's look at the question in your comment:

> Is anything wrong with "I was shared a document"?

Yes, there is something wrong with it. Let's take this out of the passive voice:

> Someone shared a document with me.

You can see that *me* is the *indirect object* rather than the *direct object*. This is because the verb *share* acts directly on *document*. *Me* is one step down the line, as the recipient of the document.

You can't mix indirect and direct objects; indirect objects must (with some exceptions, which we'll take up next) be included as a prepositional phrase: typically using *to* or *for*. So, let's look at how to change this into the passive voice:

> A document was shared with me [by someone].

Now, this is further complicated because some verbs work with both the direct and the indirect objects so often that the preposition optionally drops out. When this happens, your construction is ok.  *Give* is an example of this. Consider these sentences:

> Someone gave me a document.
>   Someone gave a document to me.

Both of these sentences are equivalent in meaning. The first sentence is sort of an abbreviated form of the second, and has become regular usage. (The same is not true of *shared*; *Someone shared me a document* wouldn't be considered correct. If that sounds arbitrary, well, it is!)

So, either of these renderings into the passive voice are fine:

> A document was given to me.
>   I was given a document.

But this is only true if, in the active voice, the preposition can be dropped for the indirect object, with the particular verb in question. If you become proficient in casting sentences back and forth between active and passive voice, it will help you determine which verbs you can use in this manner.

It will also help you to read the article on ditransitive verbs that Cardinal linked in his comment, which contains further explanation of the subject.